# Object doesn't support this action in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

In this library get an error Object doesn't support this action

Are there any fixes for this issue

Thanks 
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZ1su.png)

```
Timeline = {
    onLoad: function (e) {


        var onRender = new CustomEvent("onTimelineRender", {
            detail: {
                timeline: e.target
            }
        });
        document.dispatchEvent(onRender);
    },
```

Comment: Which is "this" library?

Comment: Please share full source that is in context of the problem

Comment: timeline.js . its using for twitter feed